# Use Props in Styled Component to Change Style *Name* (Not Value)

Tags: styled-components

Styled Components let you use props in your CSS, eg.:

```
styled.whatever`
margin: ${props => props.bigMargin ? '20px' : '5px'}
`;
```

However, I just tried to use the props in the style *name* instead:

```
styled.whatever`
margin-${props => props.leftmargin ? 'left' : 'right'}: 10px;
`;
```

and when I do that, in the Chrome debugger it looks like:

```
margin-right: ;
: 1em;
```

Is it not possible to change your style names using props, or am I just doing it wrong somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get it to work was to put both the name *and* value into the `props`-controlled part:

```
${({ leftmargin }) =>
leftmargin ? `margin-left: 1em` : `margin-right: 1em`}};
```

This works, but if anyone has a better answer (a "DRY-er" one), I'll happily accept it.